# Matrix representation of Automata

Tags: automata

Is anyone know if there is any tutorial for the matrix representation of automata?? I am taking a theoritical computer science in this semester and the professor uses the matrix in his lecture. I gonna have test next week so I have to study for it. I tried to find any tutorial on good but there was not useful tutorial.. doe anyone know any tutorial??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix} $ where the entries are alphabet letters and $A_{ij} = a \iff$ there's an $a$ transition from state $i$ to state $j$ labeled $a$.  Then $A^2 = \begin{pmatrix} a^2 + bc & ab + bd \\ ca + dc & cb + d^2\end{pmatrix}$, where $+$ means language union.  Each entry is the language of all $2$-length substrings of your automata from state $i$ to state $j$.  A similar statement holds for $A^k$.

Take the language $b^* a$ which has automata $0 \to^a 1$, $0 \to^b 0$, where $0$ is the starting node and $1$ the final node.  Its matrix looks like

$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
b & a \\
\varnothing & \varnothing
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$
A^k = \begin{pmatrix}
b^k & b^{k-1} a \\
\varnothing & \varnothing
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Exercise: prove the above characterization.

Let $f(1), \dots f(k)$ be fhe final states of an automaton $A. \ $  Then the language accepted by $A$ can be calculated using its matrix, also called $A$:

Let $B = A^0 + A^1 + \dots \ $  Then $L(A) = B_{1f(1)} + B_{1f(2)} + \dots + B_{1f(k)}$, where $1$ is the starting state.

Let's consider the boolean automata
$1 \rightarrow^0 2 \circlearrowright^1\\
\downarrow^1 \nearrow_0\\
3$

Directly represent it as the matrix $A$ where $A_{ij}$ holds the strings of length $1$ from state $i$ to state $j$:

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
\varnothing & 0 & 1 \\
\varnothing & 1 & \varnothing \\
\varnothing & 0 & \varnothing
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.. Could you explain the matrix representation with boolean?? I think your explanation is same as the transition table...isnt it?

Comment: What do you mean "with boolean"?  :D

Comment: All entries with 0 or 1. I think it is automata with alphabet $\{0,1\}$ but I am not sure. My professor talks about cantor set and myhill-Neroad theorem and other theorem with matrix 0,1. Do you have any idea?? If you dont understand my question, it is fine..My english is not so good to explain in detail.

Comment: @eChungoo I added to my post

Comment: Each matrix actually represents many automata (by changing around start and final states).

Comment: Oh, Thank you very much...

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @eChungoo  Note that this is different from the meaning presented in the links by the other answerer. lulz

Answer (score 3):

There is a power point at http://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~deepakd/fmcs-05/MAAT_final.pdf. I am not quite sure if this is what you are looking for or if you have already seen it. There is also this which might be helpful http://planetmath.org/matrixcharacterizationsofautomata. Hopefully one of these can help!

Answer (score 3):

I do not quite agree with the second part of EnjoysMath's answer about Boolean representations although I fully agree with the first part.

Let me first remind you the definition of the two operations on the Boolean semiring $\mathbb{B}$. The addition on $\mathbb{B}$ is defined by 
$$
0 + 0 = 0 \text{ and } 0 + 1 = 1 + 0 = 1 + 1 = 1
$$ 
and the multiplication by 
$$
0 \cdot 0 = 0 \cdot 1 = 1 \cdot 0 = 0\text{ and } 1 \cdot 1 = 1
$$
Let $M_n$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{B}$. The product of two such Boolean matrices is defined in the usual way, except that addition and product are of course the Boolean ones. Then $M_n$ is a monoid under the Boolean matrix multiplication.

Let $\mathcal{A} = (Q, A, E, I , F)$ be an automaton (deterministic or not) with $n$ states.
The **Boolean representation** of $\mathcal{A}$ is the monoid homomorphism $\mu$ from $A^*$ into $M_n$ defined as follows: for each letter $a \in A$, $\mu(a) = \bigl(\mu(a)_{p,q}\bigr)_{(p, q) \in Q^2}$ is the matrix defined by
$$
  \mu(a)_{p,q} = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if there is a transition $p \xrightarrow{a} q$} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Since $\mu$ is a monoid morphism, this suffices to define $\mu$ on $A^*$ ($\mu(1)$ is the identity matrix and $\mu(a_1 \dotsm a_k) = \mu(a_1) \dotsm \mu(a_k)$, but $\mu(u)$ can be also defined directly by setting
$$
  \mu(u)_{p,q} = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if there is a path $p \xrightarrow{u} q$} \\
    0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
See this [paper](http://www.liafa.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/York.pdf), Section 4.

Comment: I think your explanation fits what I learned in class..can you explain what is monoid homomorphism?? This is something I did not learn yet..thanks

Comment: @echung00 The definition is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid#Monoid_homomorphisms). Given two monoids $M$ and $N$, a function $f: M \to N$ is a morphism if $f(1) = 1$ and for all $x, y \in M$, $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.